# How can I set dialog width in ngDialog

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

I'm simply trying to set the width of the dialog box, and I haven't succeeded (yet). I have added a CSS class, but the width set is the one of the dialog shade.

```
.dialogwidth800 {
    width : 800px;
}
...
ngDialog.openConfirm({
    template: 'templateRemove',
    className: 'ngdialog-theme-default dialogwidth800',
    scope: $scope
}).then(
```

EDIT : fiddle corrected with working solution here : https://jsfiddle.net/jr626fww/8/

Comment: The class name of modal content is **ngdialog-content**
CSS: .ngdialog.dialogwidth800 .ngdialog-content{width : 800px;}

Comment: @wZVang is right , apply width to the class .ngdialog-content.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used @wZVanG solution, and I edited the Fiddle.

Answer (score 14):

It can easily achieved by using custom css like below :

```
.ngdialog.ngdialog-theme-default.custom-width-800 .ngdialog-content {
    width: 800px;
}
.ngdialog.ngdialog-theme-default.custom-width-900 .ngdialog-content {
    width: 900px;
}
```

Use these css class when you open **ngDialog** :

To use **custom-width-900**

```
ngDialog.openConfirm({
    template: 'templateRemove',
    className: 'ngdialog-theme-default custom-width-800',
    scope: $scope
});
```

To use **custom-width-900**

```
ngDialog.openConfirm({
    template: 'templateRemove',
    className: 'ngdialog-theme-default custom-width-900',
    scope: $scope
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Apply width with class `.ngdialog-content{width :100px !important;}` Using !important is very important to override any css property

Comment: Use "!important" at least used when needed and there is no way to edit the class. However, this time, you can get the results by adding the class to the main class: .ngdialog.dialogwidth800 .ngdialog-content {...}

Comment: This solution affects all ngDialogs. @BharatBhushan

Comment: @betomoretti did you find a proper solution for this?